# How to separate scatter plots using decision boundary?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, scatter-plot

I'm currently working on this dataset that relates to the top hits songs on Spotify from 2010 to 2019, and I am using Logistic Regression to work on the relationship between the speechiness of the songs (dependent) and the duration and valence respectively (independent). I am having troubles trying to convert the numerical values of the speechiness of the songs into binary values for classification, as I am using logistic regression. Additionally, I do not know how to separate the scatter plots with a decision boundary. It would be deeply appreciated if anyone can help me with this.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 

df = pd.read_csv('top10s [SubtitleTools.com] (2).csv')

def LogReg0732():
    Dur = df.dur
    Dur = np.array(Dur)
    Dance = df.dnce
    BPM = df.bpm
    BPM = np.array(BPM)
    Energy = df.nrgy
    Energy = np.array(Energy)
    dB = df.dB
    dB = np.array(dB)
    Live = df.live
    Live = np.array(Live)
    Valence = df.val
    Valence = np.array(Valence)
    Acous = df.acous
    Acous = np.array(Acous)
    Speech = df.spch
    Dance = np.array(Dance)
    Pop = df.popu
    Pop = np.array(Pop)

    Speech = (Speech < 8).astype(int) 

    Speech = np.array(Speech)

    X = Dur

    X = np.stack((X, Valence))

    y = Speech

    clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X.T, y)
    print("Coef ", clf.intercept_, clf.coef_)
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[np.min(Dur):np.max(Dur), np.min(Valence):np.max(Valence)]
    gridxy = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
    probs = clf.predict_proba(gridxy)[:,1].reshape(xx.shape)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
    contour = ax.contourf(xx, yy, probs, 25, cmap="BrBG", vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ax_c = f.colorbar(contour)
    ax_c.set_ticks([0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1])
    idx = np.where(y==1); idx = np.reshape(idx,np.shape(idx)[1])
    y1 = X[:,idx]
    idx = np.where(y==0); idx = np.reshape(idx,np.shape(idx)[1])
    y0 = X[:,idx]
    ax.scatter(y1[0,:], y1[1,:], c='green')
    ax.scatter(y0[0,:], y0[1,:], c='blue')
    plt.xlabel('Duration')
    plt.ylabel('Valence')
    plt.savefig('LR1.svg')
    plt.show()

LogReg0732()
```

[My current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GENq.png)

[Type of graph I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2X6Q.png)

[My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2zKA.png)

Comment: Do you have a **specific technical issue**? Stack Overflow is not meant for guides or tutorials. Also, sharing screenshots is discouraged, do so only if it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your graph doesn’t look as you’d wish it to look is because the regression algorithm you’re using can’t classify "speechiness" as this or that, true or false, one or zero. Your code is fine. While your graph doesn’t look as you’d like it to look, it does look as it ought to look – the graph is an accurate representation of the data. The reason the data isn’t resolving nicely into categories is because the categories aren’t in the data in the first place.

I think you may need to reconsider your initial premise. "Speechiness", if it’s anything at all, seems to be a numerical value. If it’s a numerical value, then your problem is a regression problem, not a classification problem.

I know next to nothing about "speechiness" but a quick google suggests it’s not quite in the same league as length, width and height as regards measurable components of material reality. I would be concerned that there may be less to "speechiness" than meets the eye, and it is unlikely to be something worthy of scientific study.